# Автозаполнение формы Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, форма

Есть программа для Windows AutoIt. На ней у меня был простой скрипт который отправлял в браузерной версии whatsapp Определенное сообщение, определенному человеку каждый час.

Сейчас ноутбук временно на Linux Mint. И вот тут и появился вопрос. Как реализовать данную фичу под это прекрасной ОС? Возможно в будущем останусь под это системой.

Comment: xmacrorec/xmacroplay?

Comment: Если в браузерной, то можно просто юзерскрипт для браузера написать

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. А можно пример или ссылку на пример скрипта для браузера? Если есть возможность.

Comment: @Zer00ne, по юзерскриптам уже в гугле полно всего :)

Comment: Всем спасибо. Буду читать. Искать. Теперь хоть знаю куда копать.